# ListView Items not showing in ListView and columns disappear

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView in a tab control on a WinForm. When the form first loads I can see all the headers as expected:

[image]

I populate the ListView with details of files:

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(trNode.Tag.ToString(), "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
int fileNo = 1;
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
{
    FileInfo oFileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(new string[] { fileNo.ToString(), oFileInfo.Name, oFileInfo.Extension, oFileInfo.Length.ToString(), oFileInfo.CreationTime.ToString() });
    lvFiles.Items.Add(lvi);
    fileNo++;
}
```

Once the form has loaded the column headers have disappeared and no items show.

[image]

I have no code to change the visibity of the ListView or any containers.  As you can see after the load there is a scroll bar for the ListView which I'm guessing suggests its not hidden.

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

**UPDATE**

The listview Items.Count tells me there are item in the listview.  Even stranger is that if I change the view to SmallIcons I see them, in Details view they disappear! If I break the code and look at the items they look fine with the right data in all the right places!

Comment: Is there any way you can run this with the debugger and check whether the listview actually contains the items you are adding? like put the lvFiles.items.count on a watch or something and make sure they are increasing just to be sure.

Comment: Also i just noticed that on the second part, after you have "added" the items, you lose your columns headers? is that true or is it just because of the scrolling or something?

Comment: Posted code works.  Any other panels involved?  ListViewGroups, etc?

Comment: @metinoheat Good point, ive just got home but will ras back in and check.  But yes as the picture shows the column header disappear BUT the listview does have a scroll bar when enough items are loaded to warrant one.

Comment: @LarsTech  Yes the listview sits in a TabControl

Comment: @metinoheat Please see my update in the main post.

Comment: I have no idea. Sorry :(

Comment: does your data only populate single column?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer to this problem was something very embarrassing!  You may say a school boy error.

A line of code in a routine that clears the form I had missed a vital element.

`lvFiles.Clear();` which obviously clears everything including the headers, I changed it to `lvFiles.Items.Clear();` It was one of the first things I looked for and cannot believe I missed it. :(

Comment: This was very useful to me. I just did the same exact thing, so you're not alone on this!

Comment: This is a perfect example of the usefulness of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not quite my issue, but similar kind of mistake and maybe be useful to someone else. It turned out I had forgotten to change the paths (in xml) for the data bound to the columns, after changing the objects. Removing the columns temporarily assisted in finding this.

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(trNode.Tag.ToString(), "*.*",      SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
int fileNo = 1;
int ctr = 0
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
{
    FileInfo oFileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

    lvFiles.Items.Add(fileNo.ToString());
    lvFiles.Items[ctr].SubItems.Add(oFileInfo.Name);
    lvFiles.Items[ctr].SubItems.Add(oFileInfo.Extension);
    lvFiles.Items[ctr].SubItems.Add(oFileInfo.Length.ToString());
    lvFiles.Items[ctr].SubItems.Add(oFileInfo.CreationTime.ToString());
    fileNo++;
    ctr++;
}
```

hope it helps